# Select-options as FM parameter

Tags: abap

How can I pass my select-options as a Function Module parameter?

I have a program, with some parameters, and need to pass the select-options parameter to a Z_FM to be used in a select statement.

Comment: Is the same if the FM will work as RFC?

Comment: Function Modules are obsolete for the most part. You should probably avoid using them if possible. It may make more sense to use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it dumps an error for the length.

The solution is to use an auxiliary table.

```
DATA t_aux TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF efg_ranges.

t_aux[] = param_range[];

CALL FUNCTION 'Z_MYFM'
  TABLES
    range_param = t-aux.
```

This should work.

The problem is select-option sets the lengths of low and high depending on the table-filed used to define the select-options.

rfg_ranges have a fixed length of 45.

Answer (score 1):

In your Function Module definition, at the tables section, define a table LIKE RFG_RANGES.

Your FM will look like

```
  TABLES
      range_table STRUCTURE  EFG_RANGES
```

Then you can use it as if it were your original select-options parameter.

```
WHERE field IN range_table
```

**This worked in a FM used as RFC**
Hope this helps

Comment: I get an error:CALL_FUNCTION_CONFLICT_LENG. "P_DOCS" is the correct type, its length is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share the full solution.

Parameters:

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: p_docs FOR bkpf-belnr.
```

Call the FM.

```
DATA taux TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF efg_ranges.

taux[] = p_docs[].

CALL FUNCTION 'ZCRIP_GET_PG'
  EXPORTING
    soc           = p_bukrs
    fecha_ini     = fini
    fecha_fin     = ffin
  TABLES
    documentos    = taux.
```